# Late 2011 MacBook Pro SSD Install - Error 3403F

Tags: ssd

Im installing a new SSD on a late 2011 MacBook Pro and keep getting the error 3403F. After researching the error code, it seems that it’s my internet connection. Booting via command+R prompts a network selection. Booting via command+shift+option+R (Which I need to install the old OS) does not. I have tried moving closer to the router and plugging directly in. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you verified your internet connection is good?  Can you connect to  your SSID?  Finally, do you have another Mac from which to download and create a a macOS USB installer?

Comment: I have verified that the network is connection is good and connected to my SSID from another device but unfortunately I do not have another Mac to create a macOS USB installer

Comment: Can you connect to your SSD from the Mac that needs the fresh install?   If that Mac doesn’t  join that network, it won’t be able to use the internet to download the macOS installer.  Do you have the original drive?  Can you reinstall it?